# Shard Size in 32-bit?

Tags: mongodb

I am working with sharding and have two shards in single machine.In 32-bit machine they had mentioned the maximum mongodb size is 2GB. So for testing purpose i am have configured Shards in same machine...I have configure sharding according to the sample configuration session.[http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/A+Sample+Configuration+Session] Inspite of this reason i questioned whats the the maximum size of each shard......

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, you are sharding 2 gigs of data across 2 32-bit Mongo instances, thus putting 1 gig of data on each machine?

Comment: Hi, Rich i had edited my Question as you suggested to be precise..Thank you for ur comments.....Please check now....

Comment: If someone's answer solves your question, you should click the tick/check next to their answer.

Comment: @SampathKumar - no problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988819/database-over-2gb-in-mongodb/2989791#2989791) will probably answer your question.