# For 32-bit sharding whats the size limit of each shard?

Tags: mongodb

I am using 32-bit mongodb for sharding.I configured two shards on two 32-bit machines.Each machine has one shard...The max size of all shards is 2GB or Each shard size is 2GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each individual shard will be limited to 2GB.

Comment: Hi,Brendan W. McAdams...I reallly very much thankful to you........Your ansswer is very much precise...

Answer (score 0):

You might find this previous answer useful: [Shard Size in 32-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744557/shard-size-in-32-bit)

Comment: Hi, I couldnot understand their answer is not precise......I have shards in different machine......So that i ask whats the size of the each shard-2GB each or all the shard size is 2 GB?