# Mongodb32-bit limitation is for single database?

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb-v2.0. I have gone through the 32-bit mongodb limitation of "2GB". The thing which baffling me is 2GB limitation. I will explain our scenario :-
When the database reaches 2GB. It is possible to use different database name in a single instance.If so then each database will have 2GB? Can we use different instance of mongodb listening on different port. If its possible,then can we continue in creating new database until it reaches 2GB of size?. In this way can we use multiple database of size 2GB on 32-bit mongodb on 32-bit machines?

Thanks,
sampath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2GB are the storage limit for the mongodb server. See in the FAQ http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/FAQ#FAQ-Whatarethe32bitlimitations%3F

But maybe this is your solution: [Database over 2GB in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988819/database-over-2gb-in-mongodb)